# Amazon ec2 instance with ipython notebook

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ipython

I launched a micro instance in amazon EC2. As I would like to use ipython notebook, I chose the linux image called ami-74d00c1d, that contains ipython notebook ready to go. Now I would like to create a web page using drupal in the same instance. So I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any documentation about the organization of the ami? Where are the python files, where is the apache config...
2. How can I change the instance config, to point the root to another page instead of the ipython notebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any documentation about the organization of the ami.

But to config the ipython notebook start page, the ipython documentation ( http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/htmlnotebook.html#quick-howto-running-a-public-notebook-server ) presents a very good explanation.